# Что означает точка после числа?

Tags: c++, типы-данных, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, арифметика

Есть такая часть в коде.

```
double n = 1.;
n *= 1. / 16;
```

что . может означать?

Comment: Точка означает, что это число с плавающей точкой -  pun intended.

Comment: А что значит число с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @zip, что это вещественное число

Comment: А что такое вещественное число :)
мне бы по простому как то можно объяснить что она дает.

Comment: Вы действительно не знаете, что такое десятичная дробь? `1.3`, `2.5`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Деление

```
1/16
```

рассматривается компилятором как целочисленное деление, дающее в результате целое число, и результат в результате :) округляется до целого числа - 0.

Деление

```
1./16  // то же самое, что и 1.0/16
```

рассматривается как деление вещественного ("обычного" дробного числа из школьной математики, тип `double`) числа, так что результат получается

```
0.0625
```

(Замечу в скобках, что в C/C++ пишется десятичная точка, а не запятая.)